# Salvar último valor na variável e exibir

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis

Estou com um problema no meu programa a função dele é exibir na tela o quanto de memória ram o processo está consumindo no momento e exibir o pico de uso de memoria ram, so que o meu problema está quando eu fecho o processo, o programa para de exibir o pico de memoria ram.

Aqui a parte do código que exibe o pico de memória ram:

```
        public string vmax()
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName(label92.Text);
       double avvv = 0;
       string abi = null;
        try
        {

                if (ieProcs.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in ieProcs)
                    {
                        String physicalMem = p.PeakWorkingSet64.ToString();
                        abi = physicalMem;
                    }
                }

                avvv = double.Parse(abi);
               avvv = avvv * 0.001 / 1024;
            return avvv + " K";


        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label90.Text = vmax();
    }
```

Com o processo da calculadora aberto:
[image]

Com o processo da calculadora fechado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que mesmo quando eu fechasse o processo ele continuasse exibindo o último valor registrado pelo pico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo os detalhes passados, segue uma alteração com base no que você precisa. A ideia pelo que entendi é monitorar o consumo de memória de um processo na sua aplicação, e registrar o maior valor verificado, se o processo for finalizado sua aplicação deve manter o valor mais alto registrado até o momento, correto?

Criei um pequeno form de exemplo onde informo o nome do processo(no meu caso calc).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que no label Pico estou mostrando o maior valor registrado, isto é feito pelo código que adicionei ao seu método vmax:

```
 if (avvv > valorMax)
   valorMax = avvv;
 lblPico.Text = valorMax + "K";
```

O código acima foi adicionado imediatamente antes do *return*. Lembrando de declarar uma variável na classe:

```
private double valorMax;
```

A medida que vou usando a calculadora do windows(calc), o "valor atual" vai sendo modificado bem como o do Pico(caso o atual seja maior que o último pico registrado). Mesmo que eu finalize o processo, ou seja, feche a calculadora, o valor do pico é mantido e assim que eu abrir novamente o processo o pico ainda estará lá.

A não ser que você deseje registrar isso mesmo que a sua aplicação seja finalizada, acredito que atende sua necessidade. Para perpetuar isso bastaria salvar o último pico em um xml ou txt, e quando a aplicação abrisse novamente carregar o valor.